# What is the place to ask about legal issues associated with using software?

Tags: discussion

What is the place to ask about legal issues associated with using software? I [asked one question](https://superuser.com/questions/506449/how-to-find-out-exactly-which-registry-and-settings-files-changes-in-windows-xp) that was closed as off-topic, so I guess that superuser is not a good place to ask. Do you know any alternative?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Nowhere for now. There are [couple](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40687/rules-and-laws) of [sites](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44823/legal-questions) in [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com), but I doubt they're going to take off anytime soon.

Also, I'd note that the question you mention is more suited for forum/chat room discussion than Q&A.

Comment: "Nowhere" in the Stack Exchange network, at least.