# Are licensing questions / license questions off topic

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the place to ask about legal issues associated with using software?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5908/what-is-the-place-to-ask-about-legal-issues-associated-with-using-software)

Are questions about licensing on or off topic here?

It does have a lot to do with software/hardware yet, at the same time it's also not related!

**EDIT**

For example, [Does the license allow me to run Windows 7 in a virtual machine and on the host?](https://superuser.com/questions/530432/does-the-license-allow-me-to-run-windows-7-in-a-virtual-machine-and-on-the-host#530432)

Comment: Always a tough call, but I'd say, if it takes a lawyer to answer, then definitely off topic. If the question is how the license affects what you're doing on your computer (if it allows you to do this and that, or install something, etc), then it should be on topic, e.g.: [Windows 7 and Vista Activation FAQ: How do language, version, 64-bit or 32-bit, and source affect ability to install and transfer Windows licenses?](http://superuser.com/questions/303136/windows-7-and-vista-activation-faq-how-do-language-version-64-bit-or-32-bit)