# Burninate or clean up the tags [open-source] your help is much appreciated

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

Since the last [request](https://meta.superuser.com/q/8997/172747) did work perfectly,
could we burninate or clean up the tag [open-source](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/open-source)?
It's a meta tags without explanation about the topic, usually used for off topic searches for software or licence issues.

Comment: It does have a wiki-definition, it is just widely abused.  Where it is incorrectly used to refer to freeware, that would be a good place to start whittling it down.  For guidance on what license use would be on/off topic, see @slhck's comment here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6153/are-licensing-questions-license-questions-off-topic.  Let's cull it and look for any questions that aren't clearly off-topic.  I'm not sure whether there is a legit on-topic usage here.  It could be that there are some good questions that should be migrated somewhere else (one of the programming sites?).

Comment: Found a couple so far that are actually appropriate usage: http://superuser.com/questions/420180/reputable-access-password-recovery; http://superuser.com/questions/10012/guidelines-for-recommending-open-source-vs-closed-source

Comment: @fixer1234 could you please wait for discussion and community consensus on this before you go nuking tags. The procedure we would like to is highlighted at http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8123/a-new-way-to-clean-up-tags

Comment: @Mokubai - I was just trying to whittle away cases of obviously improper tag usage, not nuke all of the [open-source] tags.  I'll stop.

Comment: @fixer1234, I wasn't meaning to outright stop you from doing things that are good for the community, because I do actually approve of what you are doing. I would just prefer we stick to the procedure that was laid out, because it was a bit of a free-for-all and a mess before with some people removing tags while others re-applied them and no real benefit.  Give it a day or two for this to gain a few votes and then we can set it as a planned and get rid of the tag properly.